# C++ overloading operator, compiler doesn't see the operator

Tags: operator-overloading, overloading

CMagazin.h

```
class CMagazin
{
    char *m_nume;
    list<CProdus*>List_produse;
public:
    void printExpirabile( const char* data);
    ~CMagazin();
};
```

CMagazin.cpp

```
void CMagazin::printExpirabile(const char *xdata)
{
    list<CProdus*>::iterator it;
    for (it = List_produse.begin(); it != List_produse.end(); ++it)
    {
         CProdus* p = *it;
        if (p->get_tip()=='A')
        {
            **if (p > xdata)**->this problem

        }
    }
}
```

CAliment.h

```
class CAliment :
    public CProdus
{
    char *m_expirare;
public:
    bool operator >(const char*date);
    ~CAliment();    
};
```

CAliment.cpp

```
bool CAliment::operator>(const char * date)
{
    if (atoi(this->m_expirare) < atoi(date))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

its about ">" operator.in CMagazin.cpp dont use my operator...i need help.
what can i do?I need ">" in CMagazin class. class CAliment its  a class derived from CProdus.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is: in Class CProdus the operator must be declared virtual, and in 
CMagazin.cpp

```
        void CMagazin::printExpirabile(const char *xdata)
    {
        list<CProdus*>::iterator it;
        for (it = List_produse.begin(); it != List_produse.end(); ++it)
        {
             CProdus* p = *it;
            if (p->get_tip()=='A')
            {
                if (p->operator>( xdata))-> make this!
                     {
                       p->print();
                     }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

CProdus*p - is a pointer , need to have object for use this operator -> Try (*p)>xdata

```
  void CMagazin::printExpirabile(const char *xdata)
{
    list<CProdus*>::iterator it;
    for (it = List_produse.begin(); it != List_produse.end(); ++it)
    {
         CProdus* p = *it;
        if (p->get_tip()=='A')
        {
            if ((*p)>( xdata))-> make this!
                 {
                   p->print();
                 }
        }
    }
}
```